# Using single access token to get the 'likes' of other users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Using the normal Facebook website, one can get to a page showing which pages a user has 'liked'.

From the graph API, it is possible to get this for pretty much all pages, using graph.facebook.com/userid/likes?access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN.

However, I need to be able to do the same - i.e. get the list of pages a user has 'liked' for normal Facebook users (and not 'pages' who have 'liked' other pages).

Is this possible with the single access token?  Judging by the fact you can get this info from the normal Facebook web page, I would expect it to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Privacy works slightly differently for applications accessing the API and for users accessing the actual site.

An application doesn't have access (by default) to your friends' likes to prevent data mining. In order to get a users friend's likes, you'll need to request the `friends_likes` permission.

You can read about this permission and others [in the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/).

Comment: How about if my access token has page admin rights for a page which a bunch of users 'like'.  Is there any way that same access token expect to see (via API) the other likes of those users?

Comment: @james - absolutely not. Those users have not granted you any permissions to see their likes. You'll have to have an appropriate token to get data from a user.

Comment: So why then does it often work with 'pages', e.g. justinbieber\likes gives results, i.e. who "justinbieber" likes, but a-random-user\likes gives empty results in the graph api?